# Strong Data Processing Inequality for capped channels

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, it.information-theory, markov-chains, coding-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two $\rho$ correlated Gaussian vectors, such that $X,Y\sim N(0,1)^n$ and $E[X_iY_i]=\rho$.
Let $M_X = f(X)$ and $M_Y = f(Y)$ be $k$-bit functions of $X$ and $Y$, that is $H(X)=H(Y)=k$.

We then have that $M_X - X - Y - M_Y$ is a Markov Chain.

By the standard Strong Data Processing Inequality (SDPI), we get $I(M_X; Y) \le \rho^2 I(M_X; X) \le \rho^2 k$ and likewise $I(M_Y; X) \le \rho^2 k$.

I would like to show that $$I(M_X ; M_Y) \le \rho^2 k / 2.$$

This is motivated by the fact that when $M_X$ and $M_Y$ are seen as approximations to $X$ and $Y$, then one will need twice as good approximations when both $X$ and $Y$ are approximated, rather than if only one of them is (the case $I(X ; M_Y)$.)

I'm aware of [the general result by Yury Polyanskiy and Yihong Wu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06025), which lets one compute an end-to-end SDPI for a Markov Chain (or graph). However, in that case, it is assumed that each link loses some constant factor, wherein my case the two links $M_X - X$ and $Y - M_Y$ are rate capped rather than noisy.

Do you know any information-theoretical tricks, or known relations, that I'm unaware of which might be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if $n = k = 1$ and $X = Y$? In this case $\rho = 1$. Let $M_X = 0$ if $X < 0$ and 1 otherwise. Let $M_Y = 0$ if $Y < 0$ and 1 otherwise. Then $I(M_X;M_Y) = H(M_X) - H(M_X|M_Y) = 1$. This seems to contradict your wanted inequality.

Comment: It does unfortunately. Even for larger k and n. I still feel like there should be _some_ loss over $\rho^2 k$ when $\rho\in(0,1)$. Do you have any intuition on this?

Comment: No, no intuition unfortunately. I just tried the simplest example i could think of. The same example with arbitrary $\rho$ seems hard to evaluate though.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in the asymptotics as $\rho\to 0$. Perhaps the answer is something like $\rho^2 k/(2-|\rho|)$...

Comment: If you analyze this particular channel for $\rho$ correlated $X$ and $Y$, you get $1 - H(\frac14 + \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot\arcsin(\rho))$ where I am using $H$ for the binary entropy function. (That number is directly coming from (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255368/px0-y0-for-a-bivariate-normal-distribution-with-correlation-rho)), so perhaps that might be a good place to start to get the asymptotics you are looking for.

Comment: @Efe (I think you need a factor 2 inside $H$, but) good point. We also know that for binary sources the two-function "most informative boolean function" conjecture states $I(W_X;W_Y)\le 1-H(\frac{1+\rho}2)$ for $W_X,W_Y\in\{0,1\}$. Looks like a good conjceture for the Gaussian case is still $\rho^2/(2-\rho^2)$ or $\rho^2/(2-|\rho|)$.